# Table variable doesn't exist even though it clearly defined in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I tried to create loop from table variable.

```
do
$$
DECLARE 
    modified IDType;
BEGIN
    INSERT into modified (id) 
    SELECT i.id FROM item i WHERE i.id in ('55D6F516-7D8F-4DF3-A4E5-1E3F505837A1', 'FFE2A4D3-267C-465F-B4B4-C7BB2582F1BC');

    for p in select id from modified
    loop    
        raise notice (p.id);
    end loop;
end; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

the problem is there has an error that says:

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "modified" does not exist
  Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 5 at SQL statement
```

what I expected is the variable can be used to loop and runs normally.

this is the full query that you can try: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9caba/3
I made the query in DBEAVER app, it will have some different error message.
I suggest you can experiment with it outside sqlfiddle.

Comment: Are you the same as person as https://stackoverflow.com/users/10912304/muazhari ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "table variable" in Postgres. You can define a *record*  that has a the type of a table but that is something completely different.

Even if `idtype` is the name of a table or a record type, it still holds a single value (in case of a record, it would be a single record with multiple fields)

Why would you expect a scalar variable to be usable in a loop? Are you looking for an
[array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html)?

To loop over an array use [foreach](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY)

The SELECT also seems quite strange. You can assign a value to an array directly.

The parameter for `raise notice` needs to be a string. If you want to "print" a variable, you need to use a [placeholder](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE) in the string.

So maybe you are looking for:

```
do
$$
DECLARE 
    modified idtype[];
    id idtype;
BEGIN
    modified := array['55D6F516-7D8F-4DF3-A4E5-1E3F505837A1', 'FFE2A4D3-267C-465F-B4B4-C7BB2582F1BC'];

    foreach id in array modified
    loop    
        raise notice '%', id;
    end loop;
end; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: i want loop from tables, the "in" statement just for debugging purpose

Comment: @kurismus: then show us an example what you want to do with tables. This answers the problem in your question